# Corporate-sponsored terrorism of little children – meaning?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does this sentence mean?

> Corporate-sponsored terrorism of little children.

In

> Corporate-sponsored terrorism of little children. In English. With English. Over English.

which appears on [this ELL user profile](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/46453/teacher-kshuang?tab=profile)

Does it mean that a company invests to support kids terrorists?

Comment: Hahaha, now I understand why you had asked me this. I had totally forgotten that I had written this in my profile. My mistake; it had been correct of you to ask it as a comment. Literally, yes, it means that a company pays to scare children. Figuratively, it means that I teach children English, but sometimes, I can be too scary or too firm for a child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a joke. What this means is that companies (or the company he works for) pay him big money to terrorize children. A lot of children see the process of education as a form of torture. So, he's paid huge sums of money to torture little kids with his English lessons.

*corporate-sponsored terrorism* is a play on the expression state-sponsored terrorism. That's when the government of a state (*state* is just another word for *country* in English) is providing financial support to terrorist organizations.